# How can I determine which version of Android Studio I was using

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

So I opened an Android project in Android Studio - project I haven't worked on in over a year. I started getting a bunch of prompts to upgrade this and upgrade that (Android Studio, gradle, etc, etc). Of course, I said yes to everything. Now the project won't compile.
Is there any way to revert Android Studio to my previous state? I just need to add a small update. And yes, I know I need to figure out how to get this project to compile with all the latest updates, but I can do that later. I just need to get a small update added.

Comment: Have you checked the version control for the last commit? Go for the gradle file (module) and check the changes.

Comment: If you're planning to publish this update to Google Play, you *have* to update libraries. Maybe not to the absolute latest, but less than a year old. If you tell us what the error is and show the relevant code, it might be an easy fix to get your code compiling.

Comment: @vazy I think this problem is from Gradle. First check the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and let me know by checking `distributionUrl` (`https\://services.........gradle-7.4-bin.zip`) which version of Gradle is currently in your Android Studio. If that is 8.0 or 7.4 then downgrade it and try again. But first, let me know which version of gradle wrapper is in your Android studio.

Comment: MDEV - it says distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip it used to say distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip OH, just found an earlier commit with this: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip